# List of Views in LinearLayout inside ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to add two lists into a ScrollView and I've recently read that you shouldn't put ListViews inside a ScrollView. So I decided to try using two LinearLayouts and dynamically adding inflated views to them. Unfortunately all I'm seeing is the two text views I'm using as titles but no Linear Layouts. :/ Could someone please explain why my LinearLayouts are not not showing?

Layout Inflation:

```
ArrayList<JSONObject> sightList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    try{
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
    JSONArray m_jArry = obj.getJSONArray("Locations");

    for (int i = 0; i < m_jArry.length(); i++) 
      {
       JSONObject jo_inside = m_jArry.getJSONObject(i);
       if ("Food & Drink".equals(jo_inside.getString("Section")))
       {
           sightList.add(jo_inside);
       }
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
    sort(sightList);

    LinearLayout discounts = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.discount_list);
    LinearLayout others = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.other_list);

    for (int i = 0; i < sightList.size(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject j = sightList.get(i);
        try {
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.next_list_item, null);
            v.setId(i);
            TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            TextView subtitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
            title.setText(j.getString("name"));
            title.setTypeface(montserrat);
            subtitle.setText(j.getString("TypeOfR"));
            subtitle.setTypeface(montserrat);

            if (j.getBoolean("hasDiscount"))
            {
                discounts.addView(v);
            }
            else
            {
                title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                others.addView(v);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Activity Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/featured"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/featured"
    android:src="@drawable/bandus"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/next_info_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/featured">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/discounts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:background="@color/list_header"
        android:text="@string/food"
        android:textColor="@color/header_text"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/discount_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/discounts"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/others"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Other Food and Drink"
        android:layout_below="@id/discount_list"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:background="@color/list_header"
        android:textColor="@color/header_text"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/other_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/discounts"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

List Items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp" >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/title_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/badass_blue"
        android:textSize="17sp"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/list_header"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:src="@drawable/divider"
    android:contentDescription="@string/divider"/>

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/details"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/bluearrow"
    android:contentDescription="@string/arrow"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for the help (sorry for the long post) :)

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting any `JSONException`s?

Comment: What is what you want to get? Maybe you want ONE ListView with sections?

Comment: That could work, could u have a list view with multiple headers?

Comment: LeiNaD_87, thanks for the suggestion, if you add it as an answer I'll accept it